# Eliminate sparrow chirp from sound track

Tags: noise-reduction, noise-cancelling

I recently bought a Rode NT1 mic and Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 interface. I have setup everything in my room and **I am very satisfied with the output I get**, except for the bachelor sparrows chirping outside!

Is there anyway I can get rid of this annoying chirps?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to employ some EQ-kung fu of precise editing, and equalise unwanted frequencies out manualy. Try multiple very narrow bands (as opossed to a high-shelf EQing, which would hamper all the high frequencies, including recorded material), spiking the frequencies you don't want down. But it's going to be a hassle. Probablly not worth the effort IMHO, because you're looking at A LOT of editing and (very possibly) an extensive automation pattern. You could try with de-esser too, but chances of success are slim.

You'll probablly be better off just moving your setup around and re-recording. Try closing window and moving the gear away from it, with mic facing oposite wall, preferably with some screen from side of the window. If you did that already, maybe you should think about changing the rooms, too.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a gun

failing that, try some temporary soundproofing on the window. Higher frequencies are the easiest to dissipate. And maybe move the mic/setup around.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking how to remove these bachelor sparrow chirps from an already existing recording I would suggest using a spectral editor like the one found in Adobe Audition or, more recently in [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/). The [manual describes the feature](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/spectral_selection.html) quite well. Basically the spectral draw of the waveform allows you to see and select the bird chirps and the editing feature allows you to lower or cut completely those areas.